# Getting CrtIsValidHeapPointer Error when trying to release memory [C++]

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory

I have an exercise and I need to create an Engine class and a Car class.

Those are parts of my code:

**Car.cpp**

```
Car::Car()
{
    _engine = new Engine();
    _manufacturer = new char[10];
    _prod_year = 0;
    _color = new char[10];
}

Car::~Car()
{ 
    // Releasing allocated memory
    delete[] _manufacturer;
    delete[] _color;
    delete _engine;
}

void Car::print(void) const
{
    (*_engine).print();
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "Manufacturer:" << _manufacturer << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "Production Year:" << _prod_year << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "Color:" << _color << endl;
}
```

**Car.h**

```
class Car
{

    Engine * _engine;
    char * _manufacturer;
    int _prod_year;
    char * _color;

    public:

    /*
    * Creates a Car with the default set of attributes.
    */

    Car();
    virtual ~Car();
    inline Engine * GetEngine() { return _engine; }
    void SetEngine(Engine * engine) { _engine = engine; }
    inline char * GetManufacturer(){ return _manufacturer; }
    void SetManufacturer(char * manufacturer){_manufacturer = manufacturer;}
    inline int GetProdYear() { return _prod_year; }
    void SetProdYear(int prod_year) { _prod_year = prod_year; }
    inline char * GetColor() { return _color; }
    void SetColor(char * color) { _color = color; }
    void print(void) const;
};
```

**Engine.h**

```
class Engine
{
    /*  
        Represents an Engine with the following attributes:
        * int Hourse Power
        * char * Manufacturer
        * int Production Year
    */

    int _horse_power;
    char * _manufacturer;
    int _prod_year;

public:
    Engine();
    virtual ~Engine();
    int GetHorsePower() { return _horse_power; }
    void SetHorsePower(int horse_power) { _horse_power = horse_power; }
    char * GetManufacturer(){ return _manufacturer; }
    void SetManufacturer(char * manufacturer){_manufacturer = manufacturer;}
    int GetProdYear() { return _prod_year; }
    void SetProdYear(int prod_year) { _prod_year = prod_year; }
    void print() const;

};
```

**Exc.cpp**

```
Engine engine;
engine.SetHorsePower(150);
cout << "Current Horse Power: " <<engine.GetHorsePower()<<endl;

char * manufacturer = new char[strlen("VP") +1];
strcpy(manufacturer, "VP");
engine.SetManufacturer(manufacturer);
cout << "Current Manufacturer: " << engine.GetManufacturer() << endl;

engine.SetProdYear(1995);
cout << "Current Production Year: " << engine.GetProdYear() << endl;

cout << "\n ------------- Printing engine details -------------\n" << endl;
engine.print();
Car car;
car.SetEngine(&engine);
cout << "Current Engine: " << endl;
(*car.GetEngine()).print();

char * car_manufacturer = new char[strlen("Toyota") + 1];
car_manufacturer = { "Toyota" };
car.SetManufacturer(car_manufacturer);
cout << "Current Car Manufacturer: " << car.GetManufacturer() << endl;

car.SetProdYear(2010);
cout << "Current Car Production Year: " << car.GetProdYear() << endl;

char * color = new char[strlen("Yellow") + 1];
color = { "Yellow" };
car.SetColor(color);
cout << "Current Car Color: " << car.GetColor() << endl;

cout << "\n ------------- Printing car details -------------\n" << endl;

car.print();
```

My program is doing ok until it gets to ~Car and then I get "CrtIsValidHeapPointer".

Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Thx.

---

### **SOLUTION**

```
Engine * engine = new Engine;
engine->SetHorsePower(150);
cout << "Current Horse Power: " << engine->GetHorsePower()<<endl;

char * manufacturer = new char[strlen("VP") +1];
strcpy(manufacturer, "VP");
engine->SetManufacturer(manufacturer);
cout << "Current Manufacturer: " << engine->GetManufacturer() << endl;

engine->SetProdYear(1995);
cout << "Current Production Year: " << engine->GetProdYear() << endl;

cout << "\n ------------- Printing engine details -------------\n" << endl;
engine->print();

Car car;
car.SetEngine(engine);
cout << "Current Engine: " << endl;
car.GetEngine()->print();

char * car_manufacturer = new char[strlen("Toyota") + 1];
strcpy(car_manufacturer, "Toyota");
car.SetManufacturer(car_manufacturer);
cout << "Current Car Manufacturer: " << car.GetManufacturer() << endl;

car.SetProdYear(2010);
cout << "Current Car Production Year: " << car.GetProdYear() << endl;

char * color = new char[strlen("Yellow") + 1];
strcpy(color, "Yellow");
car.SetColor(color);
cout << "Current Car Color: " << car.GetColor() << endl;

cout << "\n ------------- Printing car details -------------\n" << endl;

car.print();

return 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Car` constructor you dynamically allocate an `Engine` and assign to `_engine`.

Then in your main program you do

```
car.SetEngine(&engine);
```

thereby changing `_engine` to point to an object you *haven't* allocated dynamically with `new`, and losing the original pointer and giving you a memory leak.

So in the `Car` destructor you try to delete a pointer you haven't allocated with `new` leading to *undefined behavior*.

There are also problems with the strings, where you do thing like

```
char * car_manufacturer = new char[strlen("Toyota") + 1];
car_manufacturer = { "Toyota" };
```

That first allocates memory, and you assign a pointer to that memory to `car_manufacturer`. Then directly afterward you make `car_manufacturer` point *somewhere else* again losing the pointer to the memory you have allocated and a new memory leak. Besides you then make set the pointer in the `car` object to the string literal `"Toyota"` which again is a pointer to memory you have not allocated with `new[]` so doing `delete[]` again leads to *undefined behavior*.

---

Solving the problem with the strings are easy, even if you don't want to use `std::string` (which is the recommended solution), and that is to *copy the string* instead of reassigning the pointer:

```
char * car_manufacturer = new char[strlen("Toyota") + 1];
strcpy(car_manufacturer, "Toyota");
```

To solve the first problem with the engine, you need to allocate the new engine dynamically too, if you *have* to call `SetEngine`.

In your `Set` function you should also free the memory already allocated, so you don't have memory leaks.

Comment: Hi, sorry for not showing the whole code (included the allocation of engine - I edited it now)..
So your solution for the literal string has worked, but i still have a problem releasing the _engine.
What should i do?

Comment: @user3731023 `Engine* engine = new Engine;`

Comment: Works perfectly.
Edited my question with a solution. Programmatically is it correct?

Btw, What's the difference between what that you have suggested (Engine* engine = new Engine), to Engine* engine = new Engine() and Engine engine; ?